# get a database connection in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

This is my source code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DBConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employee";
            String uName = "jayani";
            String uPass = "jayani";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT*FROM WORKERS";

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
                String fname = rs.getString("FIRST_NAME");
                String lname = rs.getString("LAST_NAME");
                String job = rs.getString("JOB_TITLE");

                System.out.println(id_col + "" + fname + "" + lname + "" + job);

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here i got an exception like "executeQuery method can not be used for update."
What is this exception and how can I solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: Which one do you actually use: Microsoft sql-server or MySQL?

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko seems as if it is derby :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use executeQuery like this

```
    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "select * from <tablename>";
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: Thank you, but when i used it ,i'm getting an error like "incompatible types
  required: ResultSet
  found:    int
----"..Why is that?

Comment: What is the datatype of "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME","JOB_TITLE" in database table

Comment: How? I had to use String sql = "SELECT * F\";ROM APP.Workers"; in place of  String query = "select * from <tablename>"; :)

Comment: My Bad,  that I gave you as an example only :)